# How to create custom fonts in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, typeface, directory-structure

I need to add new fonts to my project
where do i create it in android studio

Can someone advise if i create it in the correct directory in android studio?

I tried putting the fonts folder same location as SRC folder but didn't work out

my code is

```
Typeface fontRobo = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");
viewTotalValue.setText(total.toString());
```

Is this correct? please advise

Comment: create a folder into assets name it as fonts.place your font file into it .that's it .Your code to access it is correct

Comment: Go through this link if this can help
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/

Comment: I answer this question in clear way , please check it

Answer (score 14):

if you use android studio , you should create assets folder 
from right click at

app ---> New --->Folder --->Assets Folder

[image]

choose destination to your assets folder default main

[image]

create directory called fonts in assets then place your font

[image]

```
|assets

    |-----------------fonts

        |-------------------Roboto-Black.ttf

|java

|res

AndroidManifest.xml
```

finally use this code

```
Typeface fontRobo = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");
viewTotalValue.setText(total.toString()); 
viewTotalValue.setTypeface(fontRobo );
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to place your font file at the root of your project, inside a folder called 'assets'. You should end up with this structure :

```
src
|------------assets
    |-----------------fonts
        |-------------------font.ttf
|------------java
|------------libs
|------------res
AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: @m3n0R thanks, I must have missed the question was related to Android Studio. Corrected it ;)

Comment: I answer this question in clear way , please check it

Comment: why are you telling me ?

Answer (score 3):

In **android studio**, the **assets** folder have to be placed under the "**main**" folder. **Not** under the "res" folder.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android Studio uses the new Gradle-based build system, you should be putting the "assets/" folder inside of the source sets.

That was working for me:

src/main/assets/fonts/examalpefont.ttf

Answer (score 1):

You have to download custom font .ttf file. In my case I downloaded din.ttf file.
put that in app->assets->fonts->din.ttf
Write the code in MainActivity.java file

```
    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/din.ttf");
    tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

//that's it . Done!