# How to import external font/ typeface in ANDROID STUDIO?

Tags: android, fonts, android-studio

I want to know how do I use an external font in Android Studio as there is no ***Assets folder***. I have look for a helpful turtorial on internet but they all pretend to use Assets folder.

I created an asset folder myself in `src/main` but Android Studio doesnt recognie `getAssets()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create custom fonts in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997467/how-to-create-custom-fonts-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Go on your Project: app-->src-->main

Create a assets folder like this:

```
|assets

    |-----------------fonts

        |-------------------font.ttf

|java

|res

AndroidManifest.xml
```

and then use

```
     Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/digital.ttf");
     txtV.setTypeface(face);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have custom font then use following code:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Verdana.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Also place your font file in assets/fonts folder and follow the [instructions](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/) from here.

**NOTE:** You have to make asset folder by yourself

Answer (score 2):

Put your font files (e.g customfont.tff and customfont_bold.tff) under the folder app>src>res>font> (Note: If it is not present, create font folder)

Additionally, create a file named fonts.xml inside the same folder with the following content:

```
  <font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <font
                app:fontStyle="normal"
                app:fontWeight="700"
                app:font="@font/customfont"/>

        <font
                app:fontStyle="normal"
                app:fontWeight="700"
                app:font="@font/customfont_bold"/>
  </font-family>
```

Then, edit the file app>src>res>values>styles.xml to apply a default font for the entire app.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/customfont</item>
</style>
```

If you want to change the font of an individual UI element:

```
<TextView
    android:fontFamily="@font/customfont"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Some text"
    />
```

NOTE: This method is valid for API Level 16+ (For more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

Answer (score 0):

if you are having an error with "getAssets()" method then you can use following way.
in assets folder puts font family

```
Typeface getFace=Typeface.create("OpenSans",3);
textView =  (TexView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setTypeface(getFace);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'e tried both the res/asset/font and main/asset font folders and you've tried different fonts, and it failed to work -- it's likely to be an Android Studio bug.

I had the same problem but I solved it by importing my font to an online font editor (search for pentacom font editor) and exporting the font and saving it to a new ttf file. The resulting font will be lower in resolution but it worked for me.

There might be other online font editors/exporters you can try.

Answer (score 0):

According to android developers : 
Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces a new feature, Fonts in XML, which lets you use fonts as resources. You can add the font file in the res/font/ folder to bundle fonts as resources. These fonts are compiled in your R file and are automatically available in Android Studio. You can access the font resources with the help of a new resource type, font. For example, to access a font resource, use @font/myfont, or R.font.myfont.

for more details : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

> To use external fonts, first download the font in .tff format
> [Google font- Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)

> Add the font asset folder as shown in the image below

[image]

[image]

> After the font asset folder is created, copy and paste the downloaded .tff font into the "font" folder. (make sure the name is formatted well. )

> Reference the font in your theme.xml or any layout using the android:fontFamily="@font/splashfont" property.
>
> This is how you do it in a theme.xml file

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.FishPott" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_black_level_1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/color_black_level_2</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/color_black_level_1</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/color_black_level_2</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/color_white_level_1</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/robotoregular</item>
</style>
```

> This is how you do it in a textview

```
    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_start_fp_MaterialTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/splashfont"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MyText"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black_level_1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_start_logo_ShapeableImageView" />
```