# How to add fonts folder on Android Studio?

Tags: android, fonts, android-studio, directory-structure

I'm developing an android app using Android Studio IDE, and i want to use customized fonts in this app.

I know that i have to create a folder called **'fonts'** under the folder **'assets'**, but i can't.
All the time that i try, i have this:

**res

-assets.fonts**

Instead off:
**res

-assets

--fonts**

How can i create this folder?
I'm newbie on android development, so sorry about something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create custom fonts in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997467/how-to-create-custom-fonts-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Android Studio, you can create `assets` directory under `src/main`.

So it looks like this

```
- src
  - main
    - java
    - res
    - assets
      - fonts
```

#### Update

Recent support library(from 26.0) officially supports fonts as Resource.

To use this, put fonts into `src/main/res/font/`,

```
- src
  - main
    - java
    - res
      - font
```

Now you can use font as R.font.xxx

In layout xml

```
android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
```

Or programmatically

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

This feature also enables you to create font family. Further information is on [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html).

You can also use [Downloadable Font](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html).

Comment: Thank you very much ytRino, that's is the structure model that i want to know : )